# Adding Azure Active Directory authentication to a Blazor WebAssembly app

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I've got an existing Blazor Web Assembly app and I'm attempting to implement Azure AD authentication so that only users who have signed in with their work account can access the web app.

I'm attempting to follow this [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-7.0). I've got the `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal` nuget package installed however, in my `Program.cs`, I receive the following error:

```
IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddMsalAuthentication.
```

for the following block of code:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    });
```

Any suggestions on why and how to resolve this?

Comment: Installed the related package and added the mentioned code in `Program.cs` without any issues. Make sure you have installed the package in the same ( Client/Server) Application.

Comment: Once check the related `.csproj` file.

Comment: My project Folder [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq04S.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, created the `Blazor WebAssembly App`.

[image]

In `Program.cs` file, added the code which you have mentioned.

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});
```

Initially even I got the same error.

[image]

In `BlazorApp1.Server` Application, Installed the `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal` NuGet Package.

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="7.0.2" />
```

- Now I am able to build the application without any issues.

***My BlazorApp1.Server `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>BlazorApp1.Server-****</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\BlazorApp1.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\BlazorApp1.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My Folder Structure:***

[image]

- As there are two `Program.cs` files (Client/Server), make sure you have installed the package in the application where you are adding the code.